# Замена символов?

Tags: c++

```
 char line[80];
    char symb[3] = { '.','.','.'};
    char symb1[1] = { '.' };
    cout << "Input string : ";
    cin.getline(line, 80);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == symb[3])
        {

            line[i] = symb1[0];
        }
    }
```

Как заменить (...) на . ,я вот сделал что-то не получилось , как исправить?

Comment: `string` нельзя использовать ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs нет нельзя

Comment: а указатели тоже ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs указатели можно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(){
    char *line = new char[80];
    cout << "Input string : ";
    cin.getline(line, 80);

    char *new_line = new char[80];
    size_t i, j = 0;
    bool flag = true;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(line)-2; ++i){
        if(line[i] == '.' && line[i]==line[i+1] && line[i]==line[i+2]){
            new_line[j++] = '.';
            flag = false;
        }
        else{
            new_line[j++] = line[i];
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        while(i<strlen(line))
            new_line[j++] = line[i++];

    cout << new_line << '\n';

    delete[] line;
    delete[] new_line;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, я бы делал (на функции C запрета же нет?)

```
char* delEll(char * buf)
{
    for(char * s = strstr(buf,"..."); s; s = strstr(s,"..."))
        memmove(s,s+2,strlen(s+2)+1);
    return buf;
}
```

:)